# MongoDB YCSB: Connection error

Tags: mongodb, benchmarking, ycsb

I am running YCSB for mongodb and following [this](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/YCSB/blob/master/ycsb-mongodb/mongodb/README.md) document.

While loading data using:

./bin/ycsb load mongodb -s -P workloads/workloada > outputLoad.txt

a single document is being inserted into mongodb. But getting following strange name with related to hostname and connection string:

```
 0 sec: 0 operations; 
Found server connection string 
Found server connection string l
Found server connection string o
Found server connection string c
Found server connection string a
Found server connection string l
Found server connection string h
Found server connection string o
Found server connection string s
Found server connection string t
Found server connection string :
Found server connection string 2
Found server connection string 7
Found server connection string 0
Found server connection string 1
Found server connection string 7
 10 sec: 1 operations; 0.1 current ops/sec; [INSERT AverageLatency(us)=1106185] 
Couldn't insert key user8517097267634966620
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{}. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=l:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: l: Name or service not known}}]
    at com.mongodb.BaseCluster.getServer(BaseCluster.java:82)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getServer(DBTCPConnector.java:656)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.access$500(DBTCPConnector.java:40)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.getConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:505)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.get(DBTCPConnector.java:448)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getPrimaryPort(DBTCPConnector.java:407)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:184)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:167)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:93)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:78)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:120)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.MongoDbClient.insert(MongoDbClient.java:254)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.insert(DBWrapper.java:148)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.workloads.CoreWorkload.doInsert(CoreWorkload.java:461)
    at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:269)
 11 sec: 1 operations; 0 current ops/sec; [INSERT AverageLatency(us)=10005522] [CLEANUP AverageLatency(us)=10127]
```

Also, I see **l: Name or service not known** in stack trace where *l* seems to be extracted from *localhost*.

I have tried to find an issue, but this code test is not working for me.

Can someone find what's the issue with connection string? The mongodb server is up and running normally. No error was logged in mongo logs when the issue appears. I tested it with bind_ip:0.0.0.0 and different hostname that *localhost*.

Mongodb version 3.0.4, mmapv1, Apache Maven 3.0.5.